# Combine multiple csv with 'datetime' columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple **CSV** files having different no. of columns say **csv1** has **42 columns**, **csv2** has **79 columns** and **csv3** has **20 columns**. They have **DateTime** columns which is unique in all csv files. I am trying to combine all files on datetime column.

I try to use the below code however it is creating a large no. of empty columns. Please suggest an effective solution.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("/home/reports")


extension = 'csv'

all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('report*.{}'.format(extension))]


#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=';') for f in all_filenames ])

#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_report.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: By saying that DateTime column is unique in all csv files, do you mean that datetime values not repeated, e.g. different in all files? If so, then the only solution would be to convert your dataframes to `long` format.

Comment: Hi @MiteshMittal, what are you trying to achieve as a result ? Keep only the columns that are in all files ? Keep only the datetime column ? If you want all data from all files, there’s no way around the fact that files without some columns will have empty data in their rows.

Answer (score 0):

- you have described common date columns and independent data fields across CSVs
- have synthesised this. Number of columns and rows is random. Independent columns are filled with random values
- the requirement to concat / merge uses `concat()` and `groupby().first()`
- given there are many columns,  sample output is just first independent column from each CSV
- look at CSVs, update synthesis process if it doesn't match what you have described

```
from pathlib import Path

# synthesize what's described - common date columns, independent data fields per CSV
# random number of columns and rows, random values in independent columns, overlapping dates in date columns
d = {
    f"df{i}": pd.DataFrame(
        {
            **{
                f"date{d}": pd.date_range(f"1-jan-{2018+d}", periods=r)
                for d in range(3)
            },
            **{f"{i}_{c2}": np.random.uniform(1, 10, r) for c2 in range(c)},
        }
    )
    for i, (r, c) in enumerate(
        zip(np.random.randint(2, 20, 10), np.random.randint(2, 80, 5))
    )
}

# generate CSVs from synthesized DFs
for df in d.keys():
    d[df].to_csv(Path.cwd().joinpath(f"report_{df}.csv"), index=False)

# now the requirement - concat / merge them.  rows with common dates are merged
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(p) for p in Path.cwd().glob("report_df*.csv")]).groupby(
    ["date0", "date1", "date2"], as_index=False
).first().to_csv(Path.cwd().joinpath("report_combined.csv"), index=False)

# sample output
pd.read_csv(Path.cwd().joinpath("report_combined.csv")).loc[
    :, ["date0", "date1", "date2"] + [f"{x}_0" for x in range(5)]
]
```

### sample output

|  | date0 | date1 | date2 | 0_0 | 1_0 | 2_0 | 3_0 | 4_0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-01-01 | 2019-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | 4.97835 | 3.71253 | 5.01434 | 8.27109 | 2.99249 |
| 1 | 2018-01-02 | 2019-01-02 | 2020-01-02 | 5.73684 | 1.20299 | 1.85132 | 8.06872 | 9.11377 |
| 2 | 2018-01-03 | 2019-01-03 | 2020-01-03 | 2.09498 | nan | 8.0877 | 5.13207 | 2.50901 |
| 3 | 2018-01-04 | 2019-01-04 | 2020-01-04 | 9.64076 | nan | 7.33267 | 1.15581 | 7.05995 |
| 4 | 2018-01-05 | 2019-01-05 | 2020-01-05 | 5.27771 | nan | nan | 4.75795 | 2.85646 |
| 5 | 2018-01-06 | 2019-01-06 | 2020-01-06 | 4.04003 | nan | nan | 3.81245 | 1.52377 |
| 6 | 2018-01-07 | 2019-01-07 | 2020-01-07 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 4.71341 |
| 7 | 2018-01-08 | 2019-01-08 | 2020-01-08 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 8.18832 |
| 8 | 2018-01-09 | 2019-01-09 | 2020-01-09 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 3.23354 |
| 9 | 2018-01-10 | 2019-01-10 | 2020-01-10 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 8.50481 |
| 10 | 2018-01-11 | 2019-01-11 | 2020-01-11 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 4.75847 |
| 11 | 2018-01-12 | 2019-01-12 | 2020-01-12 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 3.05732 |
| 12 | 2018-01-13 | 2019-01-13 | 2020-01-13 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 4.31586 |
| 13 | 2018-01-14 | 2019-01-14 | 2020-01-14 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 7.94507 |
| 14 | 2018-01-15 | 2019-01-15 | 2020-01-15 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 3.62756 |
| 15 | 2018-01-16 | 2019-01-16 | 2020-01-16 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1.09299 |
| 16 | 2018-01-17 | 2019-01-17 | 2020-01-17 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 3.85213 |
| 17 | 2018-01-18 | 2019-01-18 | 2020-01-18 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1.14182 |

Answer (score 0):

And there is the `long` format, which could save from empty columns. I have put some code to generate fake data too.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

dates = ["2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01"]
widths = [3, 2, 1]

buf = []

for i in range(len(dates)):
    date_col = pd.to_datetime(sorted(np.round(np.random.rand(3), 4)), origin=dates[i], unit="D")
    data = np.random.rand(3, widths[i])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=date_col, columns=["col_{0}{1}".format(i, j) for j in range(widths[i])])
    df.index.name = "Date"
    df.index = df.index.floor('s')
    buf.append(df)

df = pd.concat([df.melt(ignore_index=False) for df in buf])
```

Now we have a `buf` list that contains 3 dataframes, and their datetimes are completely different from each other. If we contatenate them, in any way we will have empty columns, because neither datetime index nor column names match. Thus we have to `melt` our dataframes, e.g. put data columns on top of each other, creating a new column to store the ex-column name, and repeating datetime index as necessary. That way our dataframes will have 3 columns only: DateTime, Variable and Value. And they could be concatenated easily.

```
df = pd.concat([df.melt(ignore_index=False) for df in buf])
```

Sample concatenated dataframe, where `col_0x` is from first dataframe, `col_1x` is from second and `col_2x` is from third:

```
                    variable     value
Date
2021-01-01 15:06:02   col_00  0.656970
2021-01-01 21:23:28   col_00  0.095424
2021-01-01 22:40:30   col_00  0.012732
2021-01-01 15:06:02   col_01  0.950258
2021-01-01 21:23:28   col_01  0.485026
2021-01-01 22:40:30   col_01  0.172216
2021-01-01 15:06:02   col_02  0.553444
2021-01-01 21:23:28   col_02  0.948313
2021-01-01 22:40:30   col_02  0.069310
2021-02-01 05:41:42   col_10  0.649030
2021-02-01 09:30:05   col_10  0.766949
2021-02-01 17:18:48   col_10  0.813431
2021-02-01 05:41:42   col_11  0.915467
2021-02-01 09:30:05   col_11  0.458455
2021-02-01 17:18:48   col_11  0.553780
2021-03-01 03:07:29   col_20  0.399751
2021-03-01 06:42:46   col_20  0.393324
2021-03-01 13:10:33   col_20  0.520106
```

In expense of repetition of index and ex-column names, we now get a long format of dataframe, which is easier to visualize later.